# Unable to run npm start in create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

PROBLEM

Need to run my react project

I have install create-react-app and create a project, When I tried to run project using npm start its showing some error

When I first tried in my home dir everythings work fine, Problem only when I tried to create and run in specfic dir

*USING*
Kubuntu OS,
Nodejs : V10.15.3
npm : 6.9.0

By little bit of google I done following thing

1. Remove nodemodule and install
2. Clear npm cache and one again try it as fresh
3. Uninstall and install both node and npm
4. Access the project as root
5. When I try to : npm ls react

   - kasi@kasi:~/my/node_modules$ npm ls react

     my@0.1.0 /home/kasi/my

     `-- react@16.8.6

No other things

6. Some Google - Check point:

   - kasi@kasi:~/my/node_modules$ which node

     /home/kasi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node
   - kasi@kasi:~/my/node_modules$ which npm

     /usr/bin/npm
   - kasi@kasi:~/my/node_modules$ cd ../../../../usr/local/bin/
   - kasi@kasi:/usr/local/bin$ ls

     create-react-app  n  node  npx  tsc  tsserver

*TIP:*
All my disk are FAT type so some problem may be on symlink

7. When I try to start direct as follow

   - kasi@kasi:/media/kasi/others/reaact/myapp$ node node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js

*It show*

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /media/kasi/others/reaact/myapp/node_modules/opn/xdg-open EACCES
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I will attach log file created

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ '/home/kasi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node',

1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',

1 verbose cli   'start' ]

2 info using npm@6.9.0

3 info using node@v10.15.3

4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]

5 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~prestart: myapp@0.1.0

6 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: myapp@0.1.0

7 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/media/kasi/others/reaact/myapp/node_modules/.bin:/home/kasi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin:/home/kasi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

9 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: CWD: /media/kasi/others/reaact/myapp

10 silly lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]

11 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script

12 verbose stack Error: myapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`

12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT

12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)

12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)

12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)

12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)

13 verbose pkgid myapp@0.1.0

14 verbose cwd /media/kasi/others/reaact/myapp

15 verbose Linux 4.18.0-18-generic

16 verbose argv "/home/kasi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"

17 verbose node v10.15.3

18 verbose npm  v6.9.0

19 error file sh

20 error code ELIFECYCLE

21 error errno ENOENT

22 error syscall spawn

23 error myapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`

23 error spawn ENOENT

24 error Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 start script.

24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: `EACCESS` more often than not turns out to be a permission issue. Maybe the packages in `node modules` are private.
Maybe this link can help [https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally]

Comment: All my node module are not private